# Select files before today with GNU find

Tags: linux, find

I'm trying to select files created before today with GNU find but it does not work as I expect :

```bash
$ find log/ -maxdepth 1 ! -newermt today -name "BACKUP*OK"
log/BACKUP_copro-20230504_OK
log/BACKUP_distrib-20230503_OK
log/BACKUP_distrib-20230504_OK
$ find log/ -maxdepth 1 -daystart ! -newermt today -name "BACKUP*OK"
log/BACKUP_copro-20230504_OK
log/BACKUP_distrib-20230503_OK
log/BACKUP_distrib-20230504_OK
$
```

But I expect this file only :

```
log/BACKUP_distrib-20230503_OK
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `date -d today` prints the date with the current time. `today` != `today 00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`man find`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

> `-newerXY reference`
> Succeeds if timestamp *X* of the file being considered is
> newer than timestamp *Y* of the file reference.  The letters
> *X* and *Y* can be any of the following letters:
>
> - `a`   The access time of the file `reference`
> - `B`   The birth time of the file `reference`
> - `c`   The inode status change time of `reference`
> - `m`   The modification time of the file `reference`
> - `t`   `reference` is interpreted directly as a time
>
> Some combinations are invalid; for example, it is invalid
> for X to be t.  Some combinations are not implemented on
> all systems; for example B is not supported on all
> systems.  If an invalid or unsupported combination of XY
> is specified, a fatal error results.  Time specifications
> are interpreted as for the argument to the `-d` option of
> GNU `date`.  If you try to use the birth time of a reference
> file, and the birth time cannot be determined, a fatal
> error message results.  If you specify a test which refers
> to the birth time of files being examined, this test will
> fail for any files where the birth time is unknown.

The important part is the last part: »Time specifications are interpreted as for the argument to the `-d` option of GNU `date`.«

Let's try:

```
$ date -d today
Thu May  4 17:25:19 CEST 2023
```

`date -d today` will print the date AND time. `00:00 today` or `0 today` sets the time part to 00:00.

```
find '!' -newermt '00:00 today'
```

Comment: Now that I understand it a little more, I can even use `date -d 0` :)

Comment: @SebMa yes, `date -d0` (or `find -newermt 0`) is the shortest option. But it's quite cryptic, isn't it? :)